# How to read json data using for each loop? C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

How to read `json` data using for each loop in C# ASP.NET. I have following output data of `json` and i want to read `red` highlighted data `education` using `foreach` loop.
Here is my `json` data.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "certifications": [],
    "dateOfBirth": null,
    "education": [
      {
        "id": 29364744,
        "organization": "Texas A&M University",
        "accreditation": {
          "education": "Bachelor of Science",
          "educationLevel": "bachelors",
          "inputStr": "Bachelor of Science Computer Science",
          "matchStr": ""
        },
        "grade": null,
        "location": {
          "formatted": "College Station, TX, USA",
          "streetNumber": null,
          "street": null,
          "apartmentNumber": null,
          "city": "College Station",
          "postalCode": null,
          "state": "Texas",
          "country": "United States",
          "rawInput": "College Station, TX",
          "countryCode": "US",
          "latitude": 30.627977,
          "longitude": -96.3344068
        },
        "dates": {
          "startDate": "2005-01-01",
          "completionDate": "2009-01-01",
          "isCurrent": false,
          "rawText": "2005 - 2009"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
var response = client.Post(request);
var json = response.Content.ToString();
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Comment: Hi, please post actual json data as code block instead of image

Comment: The following may be of interest: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/).

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh But i am not able to copy from debug preview , how can i post?

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh i have updated now, please check

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh i have updated now, please check

Comment: You can query JSON data, instead of looping over it.  Look at https://github.com/jdevillard/JmesPath.Net

Comment: I'm confused if you wanna read value in your json file, Why do you wanna use  for each loop? I don't find any relationship between them, You can map json to model or just read them directly.

Comment: @XinranShen if there are many branches in education definately we use foreach loop to read all, its dynamic generating json, its reading pdf file and creating json,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
    JObject education = (JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["education"][0];

    foreach (var prop in education.Properties())
    {
        if (prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object) Console.WriteLine("\r\nName: " + prop.Name + "  Value: " + prop.Value);
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nName: " + prop.Name + " Values:");
            foreach (var p in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " -- " + p.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

output

```
Name: id  Value: 29364744

Name: organization  Value: Texas A&M University

Name: accreditation Values:
education -- Bachelor of Science
educationLevel -- bachelors
inputStr -- Bachelor of Science Computer Science
matchStr -- 

Name: grade  Value: 

Name: location Values:
formatted -- College Station, TX, USA
streetNumber -- 
street -- 
apartmentNumber -- 
city -- College Station
postalCode -- 
state -- Texas
country -- United States
rawInput -- College Station, TX
countryCode -- US
latitude -- 30.627977
longitude -- -96.3344068

Name: dates Values:
startDate -- 2005-01-01
completionDate -- 2009-01-01
isCurrent -- False
rawText -- 2005 - 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a classes with the relevant properties and pass that type to DeserializeObject.

```
    public class Education
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string organization { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public List<Education> education { get; set; }
    }

    public class Base
    {
       public Employee data { get; set; }
    }

var response = client.Post(request);
var json = response.Content.ToString();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a class with you json structure visual studio has one option
for that

[image]

After with json net you can deserialize the message

```
myObject jsonobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(json);
```